# Getting the default state color (currentColor) in a different state such as hovered

Tags: css, sass

Is there a keyword like `currentcolor` which allows us to get the color of a class in its default state?

For example, I'm trying to create a re-useable button style, and `currentcolor` keyword helps a lot until I try to create the `:hovered` state.

```
.outline-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
}

.rounded-btn {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

The default state looks the way we want and changing the `color` or the `font-size` would also adjust the rest of the properties.

[image: button]

But we want the `:hovered` state to invert the colors (white text and orange background in this case)

```
.outline-btn:hover, .outline-btn:active, .outline-btn:focus {
  background-color: currentcolor;
  color: white;
}
```

But since in this state the `color` becomes white, everything else also turns white.

Is there a way that we can achieve the behavior that we want without having to create multiple classes for the different button styles that we want?

Desired effect on hover:

[image: button on hover]

Also I forgot to mention that I am using `SCSS` if that helps.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are wanting to use `LESS` or `SASS` to build your `CSS`

Comment: @Andrew I am using `SCSS`, but not very familiar with it. Is there a functionality in `SCSS` that can solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a keyword to invert the background color here...NO. `currentcolor` is exactly what it says it is...the ***current*** color.

Comment: This would be fairly easy with some extra wrapper elements, or rather an inner span for the button label, but of course, we don't really like having to use extra markup. With SCSS all you be doing really is moving some hardcoded values to preprocessor vars, which is fine, too, but it depends on where you are currently declaring those color values.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah I'm not exactly trying to invert the colors. Just in the `:hover` it should use the color that it had before as the background color and white text.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes :) it was just interesting to me that how much re-usability I can get out of CSS these days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with CSS only. Works for any two colours, provided that one is set on `background-color` and one is set on `color`.

```css
.button--orange {
  background-color: white;
  color: orange;
}

/* CSS beyond this point is colour-agnostic - no mention of either white or orange */

.button {
  border: 0.125rem solid currentColor;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.button, .button::before {
  border-radius: 5rem;
}

.button:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  inset: 0;
  
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.button:hover span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;

  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button--orange">
  <span>Button</span>
</button>
```

This works by establishing 3 layers.

The first, `.button`, is the button itself with the default background colour and text colour that appear when not hovered.

The second, `.button::before`, is a layer that appears when hovered to invert the background colour. It uses the text colour of the button by having its background colour set to [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword). The reason we need this layer instead of simply setting `background-color: currentColor` on `.button` is because we need to keep the background colour intact for the third layer.

The third layer, `.button span`, contains the text of the button. The goal is to set its colour to the background colour of the original button on hover.

We can't simply set the `color` property because in theory we don't know what to set it to. We need to copy the parent element's background colour, but it could be anything. If there were a `currentColor` that contained the value of the parent's background colour, this would be trivial.

Instead we can use `-webkit-background-clip`, a feature which has been around for ages and is [commonly used to create gradients in text](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/), but we can use it for regular colours too. We can copy the background from the parent with `inherit` and clip it to the text, which results in the visual appearance of text that is the same colour as the parent's background.

The second layer provides enough contrast to make the text visible, and the colour swap is complete.

---

An alternative, and perhaps better, approach would be to save the text colour and background colour into CSS variables (or SCSS variables as @alexbea suggests) and then reference those in the hover states of the button. But I just wanted to prove that this question can indeed be answered as originally asked.

Answer (score 2):

this can't be done with css only

if you use helpers like SCSS or Less you could make yourself a mixin where you only insert the color you want as a parameter.

but you would still have to make several classes (as many as you need different colors) but can reuse your mixin within like this (scss example):

```
@mixin invertHover($color) {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid $color;
  color: transparent;

  &:hover {
    background-color: $color;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: $color;  
  }
}

.blue-box { @include invertHover('blue'); }
.black-box { @include invertHover('#000000'); }
```

Comment: I think on line 4 of your code block you mean to have `color: $color;` instead of set to `transparent`, then in the hover `color` set to `transparent`.

Comment: this answer is deprecated as there is wide spread support for css variables in most browsers

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, you're essentially wanting currentColor to act as a variable -- to hold a constant value. The upcoming [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) will help with this, but until they're better supported, we have Sass variables.

By defining the colors as variables you can write them out very verbosely and specifically, but only have to change the color in one place when needed.

```
$btn-color: red;
$btn-bg: transparent;

.outline-btn {
  background-color: $btn-bg;
  border: 1px solid $btn-color;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  color: $btn-outline-color;

  &:hover,
  &:active,
  &:focus {
    background-color: $btn-outline-color;
    color: $btn-outline-bg;
  }
}
```

You could go a step further and have those variables set to equal previously set variables you're using for the body/html color background, e.g., `$bg-bg: $body-bg; $btn-color: $text-color;`. I love `currentColor` as well and this isn't as clean as that, but it might be more appropriate in this case.

You can then build this out as a mixin as user6292372 noted. Something like:

```
@mixin buttonBuilder($color, $bg) {
  background-color: $bg;
  border: 1px solid $color;
  color: $color;

  &:hover {
    background-color: $color;
    color: $bg;  
  }
}

...

.outline-btn {
  @include button-builder($btn-color, $btn-bg);
}
```

Then you can easily make multiple variants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I was mostly trying to see how much re-usability I can get out of CSS. I ended up creating different classes for different colors but I'm going to give your solution a try, it looks very interesting.

Comment: You're welcome, @SoroushMirzaei. My approach would also be about creating classes for different colored buttons, though I didn't make that clear in my example. I've updated the final code block to show how I'd use the mixin to create an `.outline-btn` class. Good luck!